# Correctly generating a unique invoice id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, entity-framework

I've been asked to clean up someone else's controller code, which generates an invoice, and I've run into something I don't know how to fix.  The code in question is as follows (this is using EF 6: Code First):

```
var invid = db.TransportJobInvoice.Where(c => c.CompanyId == CompanyId)
                .Max(i => i.InvoiceId);
var invoiceId = invid == null ? 1 : (int)invid + 1;
```

The code is supposed to generate an `invoiceId` based on the company the invoice is being created for.  So a small table of this might look as follows:

```
------------------------------
| Id | CompanyId | InvoiceId |
------------------------------
|  1 |         1 |         1 |
------------------------------
|  2 |         1 |         2 |
------------------------------
|  3 |         1 |         3 |
------------------------------
|  4 |         2 |         1 |
------------------------------
|  5 |         2 |         2 |
------------------------------
```

As you can see, the `invoiceId` would be generated based on the current number of invoices for the company in question.  However, I think it's reasonable to suggest that two threads could execute the query before this line is evaluated:

```
var invoiceId = invid == null ? 1 : (int)invid + 1;
```

which would result in the same `invoiceId` being generated for two different invoices.

Is there a simple solution to this, possibly leveraging Entity Framework to do this automatically?

Comment: I deleted my answer because indeed I had overlooked that. It will work with a transaction if you move the UPDATE code to a stored procedure, together with the part that increments the invoice ID. I'm afraid you can't get away without a lock otherwise.

Comment: @MarcelN. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

Server-side:  Don't compute the max(ID)+1 on the client.  Instead, as part of the INSERT statement, compute the  max(ID)+1, via an INSERT..SELECT statement.

Client-side:  Instead of an incrementing int, generate a GUID on the client, and use that as your InvoiceID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems to be inline with jhilden's answer, although not requiring the composite key.

Comment: Not really the same as @jhiden's answer.  For my server-side solution, all you need to do is change your INSERT statement into an INSERT..SELECT.  No db schema changes required, and no transactions required, since it is a single SQL statement to do both the SELECT and INSERT.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the identity for the primary key, very important!

I would then add a column for "CustomerInvoiceID" and put a compound unique key on CustomerID and CustomerInvoiceID".

Then, create a stored procedure that will populate the field CustomerInvoiceID after it has been inserted, here is some pseudo code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_PopulateCustomerInvoiceID 
    @PrimaryKey INT, --this is your primary key identity column
    @CustomerID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @cnt INT;

    SELECT @CNT = COUNT(1)
    FROM TBL 
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
        AND PrimaryKeyColumn <= @PrimaryKey

    UPDATE tbl
    SET CustomerInvoiceID = @cnt + 1
    WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn = @PrimaryKey
END
```

Comment: I need to look into this, because this looks like what I probably want.  I wonder if there's a way to do this with code first directly.

Comment: In my opinion using a SQL stored proc is the way to go, it handles transactions automatically for you.  This solution also does not require locking (which should be avoided whenever possible, especially in high traffic websites).

Comment: I'm going to try this out.  It looks like it'll be what I need, but I'll wait before I mark this as the right answer.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd avoid using `COUNT` if the intent is to obtain `MAX`. With the right index (`CustomerId` asc, `CustomerInvoiceId` desc) it should be faster to get the maximum value and you won't get tripped up if there are any deleted values. This also needs to be done in a transaction at an appropriate [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) to make it behave correctly with other activity.

Comment: -1: A stored procedure does not automatically wrap its statements in a transaction.

Comment: @mbeckish, you are correct, stored procs don't do a transaction automatically.  I meant that my answer didn't require an explicit transaction because there is only one update statement and if 10 more records were inserted before this sproc ran it would still be correct.  I should have been more clear.

Comment: @jhiden - If two threads call this stored proc around the same time, they could both get the same ID, because you are not using a transaction to make one of the threads block until the other is finished.

Comment: @mbeckish, if you look at my sproc one of the inputs is the primary key identity field.  so if 2 threads call this at the same time their arguments will be different and their results will be different (and I believe, both correct).

Comment: @jhilden - I see what you are doing now.  If you edit your post, it will let me remove my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

A rather different approach would be to create a separate table with the `NextId` for each `CustomerId`. As new customers are added you would add a new row to this table. It has the advantage that the numbers assigned to invoices can remain unique even if you allow deleting invoices.

```
create procedure GetInvoiceIdForCustomer
  @CustomerId as Int,
  @InvoiceId as Int Output
as
begin
  set nocount on

  begin transaction

  update CustomerInvoiceNumbers 
    set @InvoiceId = NextId, NextId += 1
    where CustomerId = @CustomerId

  if @@RowCount = 0
    begin
    set @InvoiceId = 1
    insert into CustomerInvoiceNumbers ( CustomerId, NextId ) values ( @CustomerId, @InvoiceId + 1 )
    end

  commit transaction
end       

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, but I've been able to test anything, for a variety of reasons.  I'll look into this when possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an `Identity` field in SQL Server, this will be handled automatically.

Comment: But it needs to be incremented per company, not table global.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this?  `invoiceId` isn't part of the key.

Comment: How can `Identity` be coerced into generating sequential numbers for _each_ company?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the per-company part.  Why bother though.  As long as each invoiceId is unique, they will be per-company also.  There will be gaps, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You should definitely use the Identity for the primary key on the table.  You should use a separate column that is unique just for the customer.

Comment: If I were forced into such silliness, I'd use ranges, or prefixes, or something.  xxx-yyyyyyyy (where x is company, and y is the primary key)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can make the invoice id auto generated unless it's beinng threated as a foreign key (which I think it isn't).

You problem with multiple threads could be solved using a lock statement.

```
lock (myLock)
{
     var invid = db.TransportJobInvoice.Where(c => c.CompanyId == CompanyId)
            .Max(i => i.InvoiceId);
     var invoiceId = invid == null ? 1 : (int)invid + 1;
}
```

This will guarantee that only thread is executing these statements.

Be careful though, this could cause performance issues when those statements are executed alot in parallel and the query takes some significant time to execute.

Comment: Thanks Jordy.  I'd much prefer to have data integrity and sacrifice some performance, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Note - you have to be careful when using `lock` in ASP.NET, since the lock only applies to a single process.